# Sending Facebook notifications to user with app_secret

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

**I have been trying to send notifications to my users via Graph API.**

But **I was facing with "An unknown error has occurred." error. There wasn't any further information.** I was have SSL, Canvas Page and also Website integration with my App but it didn't worked.

Also Google couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of hours later, I decided to try it with another App. Voila! It worked. And then I started to look differences between them. Finally I found the source of error.

Here:

[image]

If this switch is "Yes" then you can't send notifications and get "An unknown error has occurred." error. I think it's because app_secret is not anymore safe if you embedded it in a mobile application. So, if someone reach it, will be able to send notifications to your users.

What is point of this I don't know but this is the solution. If somebody can explain it, I'd be happy.